# Rails Nested Resource Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-routes

I'm fairly new to rails and I don't think I'm understanding the routing completely. When I try to access the edit action I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in StoreController#show

Couldn't find Gear with id=edit
Rails.root: /Users/dave/rails_projects/outdoor

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/store_controller.rb:7:in `show'
Request

Parameters:

{"user_id"=>"104",
 "id"=>"edit"}
Show session dump

Show env dump

Response

Headers:

None
```

**Here is my view with the link that is throwing this error:**

```
    <li><%= link_to "Store Appearance", edit_user_store_path(@user) %></li>
```

**Here is my nested route:**

```
  resources :users do
    resources :store
  end
```

**Here is my controller**

```
class StoreController < ApplicationController
  def index
     @store = current_user.gears.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def show
     @gears = Gear.find(params[:id]).user.gears.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
  end
end
```

**Model Store**

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :storeimage, :storename
  belongs_to :user

  validates :user_id, :presence => true

end
```

**Model User**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :userimage, :remove_userimage
  has_secure_password
  has_many :gears
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy 
  has_one :store, :dependent => :destroy
  before_save :create_remember_token
  require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'
  mount_uploader :userimage, UserpicUploader

  email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :first_name,  presence: true,
                          length:  {:maximum => 50 }
  validates :last_name,  presence: true,
                         length:  {:maximum => 50 }
  validates :email,      presence: true,
                         format:  {:with => email_regex},
                         uniqueness:  {:case_sensitive => false}
  validates :password,   presence: true,
                         confirmation: true,
                         length: {within: 6..40}

  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  def name
   first_name + " " + last_name
  end

  private

    def create_remember_token
        self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end

end
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass both the `user_id` and `id` params in the URL when you're accessing a `store`  object nested under a `user`, so your URL should look like this:

```
/users/1/stores/3/edit
```

Versus:

```
/users/1/stores/edit
```

You also need to pass both of those as arguments to your path helper, ie:

```
edit_user_store_path(@user, @store)
```

Comment: ok so if I've changed the path to include the @store argument. How do I define that in the controller given the models has_one and belongs_to relationship?

Comment: Define what in the controller?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. I wasn't sure how to define the @store variable. I figured it out, thanks for your help